# Is there a way to add a directory to my PATH in zsh only if it's not already present?

Tags: zsh, path

Is there an easy way in zsh to add a directory to my PATH only if it's not already present? (or, more generally, any environment variable). I've tried:

```
PATH+=/my/directory
```

... but if that's executed twice, it gets added twice.

Comment: @uther, that's not a duplicate since that other question was for bash, while this one is for zsh which has its own very way to address this issue.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In `zsh` `$PATH` is tied (see `typeset -T`) to the `$path` array. You can force that array to have *unique* values with:

```
typeset -U path PATH
```

(here with the `U`nique attribute also added to `$PATH`, so deduplication also happens when assigning to `$PATH` instead of `$path`)

And then, add the path with:

```
path+=(~/foo)
```

Without having to worry if it was there already.

To add it at the front, do:

```
path=(~/foo "$path[@]")
```

or:

```
path[1,0]=~/foo
```

if `~/foo` was already in `$path` that will move it to the front.

Comment: Don't you mean `typeset -Ug path`? When I use `typeset -U path` in my `~/.zshrc` file, I always get back an error about nothing being in the path while the zshrc is running

Comment: @eMxyzptlk, strange. `-g` is to avoid restricting the scope, but in `~/.zshrc`, the scope is global already. Also, I've never seen `zsh` complain about an empty `$PATH` (except for the command not found errors of course).

Comment: It seems if you subsequently do a `export PATH` this resets the uniqueness attribute. Doing `export -U PATH` seems to address this.

Comment: @Von, I don't observe that in that `$path` retains its `U` attribute after `export PATH` (as shown by `typeset -p path`), but it seems deduplication doesn't happen if you assign to `$PATH` instead of `$path` unless you also set that `U` attribute to `$PATH`. See edit.

Comment: What's the point of using `path=(~/foo "$path[@]")` instead of `path=(~/foo $path)`?

Answer (score 8):

Add `export -U PATH=~/foo${PATH:+:$PATH}` to one of your startup files. The `-U` keeps only the first occurrence of a value in arrays or certain `:` delimited variables like PATH.

Answer (score -3):

You'll have to do something like:

```
if echo $PATH | grep :newpath: ; then doIfPresent; else doIfMissing; fi
```

This works only if `newpath` is delimited bu two ':', need to consider the cases when it is at the beginning or end similarly.

Urgh.

Comment: You can do that inside the shell, with only Bourne/POSIX features. This avoids quoting headaches (at least make that `echo "$PATH"`: **always put double quotes around variable substitutions**). `case ":$PATH:" in *:/new/directory:*) :;; *) PATH=$PATH:/new/directory;; esac`